Trying to compare 2 files in a batch job
I have a JCL job as follows trying to compare the contents of a dataset with an HFS file.
//CHKOUTP  EXEC PGM=ISRSUPC,PARM=(DELTAL,FILECMP)                   
//NEWDD    DD DSN=&&TMP1,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)                          
//OLDDD    DD PATH='/u/gemuser/test/expout.txt',PATHOPTS=(ORDONLY) 
//OUTDD    DD SYSOUT=A                                              

but it doesn't seem like ISRCUPC likes the HFS file. I get output thus:-
  ISRSUPC   -   MVS/PDF FILE/LINE/WORD/BYTE/SFOR COMPARE UTILITY- ISPF FOR z/OS
NEW: SYS24173.T013517.RA000.TSTQFMT.TMP1.H01                 OLD: ...PATH=.SPECIFIED...
                                                                               
                   COMPARE SUMMARY LISTING (FILE COMPARE)                      
                                                                               
DIFF SAME                      N-BYTES O-BYTES N-LINES O-LINES N-HASH-SUM O-HASH-SUM
                                                                               
 **                               1188     400       9       5  BC58F79D   CBCCC86B
PROCESS OPTIONS USED: NONE                                                     

How should I code the HFS file in my JCL to have ISRSUPC use it?
I have searched for examples of ISRSUPC but none have HFS files, all use datasets.

I think it has used it - there are no error messages and you have output indicating that the files are different (The double asterisk under the DIFF heading).
You may be getting mixed up because it's not showing all the differences, but that's because you've asked it to only indicate if the files are different, by using the FILECMP parm. Change that to LINECMP and you should get a comparison of each line.
Bear in mind that Super-C has the following compare types and options for listing it's results:
Compare Type               Listing Type 
2  1. File                 2  1. OVSUM  
   2. Line                    2. Delta  
   3. Word                    3. CHNG   
   4. Byte                    4. Long   
                              5. Nolist 

as well as a vast array of processing options, for which descriptions can be found in the IPSF HELP panels for Super-C

Oh ok - I had assumed that the OLD: ...PATH=.SPECIFIED... on the first row meant it hadn't figured out the file name I was trying to give it. Would we not expect to see the file name there, just like the NEW section to the left also on that first row?

I can confirm that it is indeed using it - so the first line should just be ignored, it is not correctly writing the file name there.

@MoragHughson Yep - I see what you mean about it not writing the OLD path correctly - that’s is a bit misleading. I haven’t used SuperC before with HFS files so not come across this personally.

I've switched to using diff. It doesn't handle HFS files well at all. I found it wasn't handling line endings and was just sticking all the lines together so files that were the same didn't match.

Are any of the process options useful? I actually sometimes need to compare HFS files but have been doing it in Notepad++ - I never thought of using SuperC. I'll give it a try.

@MoragHughson My diff skills are a bit rusty, but the follow options give a nice side-by-side layout:
diff <file1> <file2> -y --suppress-common-lines
Or if you are using Notepad++ (other editors are available), it has a 'compare' plugin that shows differences side-by-side

The "...PATH" you're seeing implies that ISRSUPC  is looking at the dataset name in one of the "legacy" z/OS data structures. A common way to get the dataset is to check the z/OS JFCB that has the DSN, but of course, a DSN is limited to 44 uppercase characters while a PATH isn't. To handle this correctly, IBM puts the "...PATH" you see in the JFCB and stores the actual pathname in a separate structure. A more sophisticated application would see that it's dealing with a PATH and fetch the actual pathname a different way.
